# Manipulating data on webs in Android

Tags: android, jsoup

Im a new Android programmer, and my question is this:

I want to fetch some info from a HTML file. What would be the best way to download it and parse it in a comfortable way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `jsoup` to parse HTML. [Here](http://jsoup.org/) you can find the jsoup library and full source code.

Here is an example: http://desicoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-parse-html-in-java-jsoup.html

To install in Eclipse:

1. Right Click on project
2. BuildPath
3. Add External Archives
4. select the .jar file

Comment: Any idea how to install it in Eclipse? I dont see the install instructions anywhere :S