# Android: Parsing webservices response and store in a local variable

Tags: android, web-services, parsing

In my  web services program I am getting the response as a string value to the logcat. the value is 1 if its success and 0 if its failure and -1 if field is empty.

I want to Parse my response answer(0 ,1) to store in a local variable and I want to show the alert like

```
 if(result==1)
                 {
           show the alert"Registered"
}

else if(result==0){
    show alert"Try Again"
}

else if(result == -1)
{
show alert "Field is empty"
}
```

How ever showing the alert is easy, but as I am new to web services, I don't know how to parse the result and store in a local variable. someone please help me to solve this

Help is always appreciated....!

```
         request.addProperty("email", email);
        request.addProperty("contact", contact);
        request.addProperty("fname", fname);
        request.addProperty("lname", lname);
        request.addProperty("gender", gender);
        request.addProperty("dateofbirth", dob);
        request.addProperty("password", password);
        request.addProperty("latitude", "76");
        request.addProperty("longitude", "82");
        request.addProperty("device_id", "12345"); 

            aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"); 
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
```

Comment: in which format you are getting response ?

Comment: @Chirag,  I m getting the response as string, see the line   Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));

Comment: do u want to parse some data from webpage and then store it in your application?

Comment: @ Rasel, yes I want to parse it from WSDL file, I mean from web page only

Comment: you can use parsing method from XML.There are several ways of doing that

Comment: @Rasel,  Ya but I dont know the approach. bit confused to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sax parsing,Dom parsing or other two parsing method if you have simple xml file in the web.If you work with complex web page then you can use Jsoup.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749) i told how to use jsoup to parse any kind of data from any pages

[here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0408.html) is the link of how you can use SAX/DOM for simple XML file parsing

Comment: Thanks  a lot. but I m parsing the only single  string value. so saxparsing is the correct approach I think.

Comment: Ok you can use either SAX/DOM parsing