# How to parse image or image url from Rss xml

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

i am pretty new to Rss parsing concept. i am doing Xml parser in java platform for my mobile app. i have been able to parse Title, description and date,but the url for image is difficult to parse from rss. tag name might be different from rss to rss. if any one having idea of how to parse image or image url please guide me. Thanks for previous replies and valuable answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAX/DOM and other are limited in there activities.However you can use Jsoup.With this you can parse image url.I am not sure about the image itself.See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749) how to use jsoup in android