# Fetching data from a url in android

Tags: android, url, emulation, fetch

I'm new to android. My applcation will query to a url and will receive the json response.
But I am unable to fetch the data from the url. I am behind the proxy server ..so have updated the APN settings in the emulator and the built-in browser working fine.

I am using the following code for getting the data...:

```
package com.android.urlfetch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


 public class UrlfetchActivity extends Activity {
Button but1;
String result ;
private TextView text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try{
        result = getStringContent("http://www.google.com");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        result = "Error";
    }

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(result);


}
 url=http://voxpopis.com");


public static String getStringContent(String uri) throws Exception {

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(uri));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader   (ips,"UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while(true )
        {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                break;
            sb.append(s);

        }
        buf.close();
        ips.close();
        return sb.toString();

    } 
    finally {

    }
} 
}
```

I tried to get the anser in stack overflow's similar questions but dint get any answer. Any help will be appreciated.

My logcat response is :

```
06-30 15:14:08.820: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 601 uid 10037
06-30 15:14:10.800: WARN/PackageManager(58): Code path for pkg : com.android.urlfetch   changing from /data/app/com.android.urlfetch-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.urlfetch-2.apk
06-30 15:14:10.800: WARN/PackageManager(58): Resource path for pkg : com.android.urlfetch changing from /data/app/com.android.urlfetch-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.urlfetch-2.apk
06-30 15:14:12.250: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(58): no available voice recognition services found
06-30 15:14:25.629: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-30 15:14:26.257: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44fd4af8 com.android.urlfetch/.UrlfetchActivity}
06-30 15:14:36.911: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(539): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

This code is working fine in direct connection ....but I am in a proxy network ...its not working in proxy network.What settings I should do to work in a proxy net?

Comment: Have you added the Internet permisson?

Comment: yes i have added trhe permission in manifest file..

Comment: i just found tht the code is working fine on direct connection...can anybody help me what changes i have to make ..for running the app in proxy network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fetching the data from the web very comfortably you can use Jsoup.To see how to work with this in android with the emulator click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749)