# how to look up info on internet and display it in text view?

Tags: android

I would like to look up information with a specific number unique to that item online. and return information about it back to the user view internet. Does any one have an idea of how i would go about doing this?

I thought about just implementing a webview and have the user pick through different links. but i want to make it a better experience.

Comment: Do u want to fetch the data from internet from specific tag?

Comment: Yeah i want to fetch the data based on a number in my SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jsoup to fetch the data.After fetching you can make the comparison with your data(comes from SQL database).To see how jsoup works with android see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749)

To parse href that contains cmd=category_details&category_id from  tag You can write following

```
Document doc = doc=Jsoup.parse("http:\\",10000);

                    Elements links=doc.select("A");
                    for(Element link:links){
                    href=link.attr("href");
                    if(href.contains("cmd=category_details&category_id"))
                    {
                    }
```

Test several function like link.ownText().This is not exactly your answer but you can definitely go with it to find the data

Comment: Thanks that looks great! one question.. How do i get this to return internet information. Not information based from a html file. Could you provide a detail example here? I will greate appreciate it. and im sure alot of other people would.

Comment: could you provide me details.Like a page URL and from that what information you want according to the information comes from your database

Comment: Url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page  idk how i would utilize the search. and then from my SQL database would be KEY_artist_name.

Comment: which search?from wikipedia search box in the upper right corner

Comment: Yeah.. I dont really know how i would utilize that. If you know you could provide it in the example you were about to give.

Comment: if you put abc on search and press enter what is url that brings you the information.It is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/abc.Right?So simply use jsoup to parse "http://en.wikipedia.org/wike/"+keyValueFromDb

Comment: Exactly thats right.. Okay so i have that part. So how would i go about getting what information i need? such as birthdate and other key info?

Comment: See the html source page.And parse according to the information you need.Get back to me if face problem

Comment: Okay im looking at the source code on Wiki. I would like to get the plot view <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Plot_summary"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Plot summary</span></a></li> which is in the wiki when i view it in source code. Could you please translate how i would do this with jsoup class? im having trouble with that.

Comment: well,I just can't tell you in few words.Look at the updated answer