# how to get data from web to android app?

Tags: android, asp.net

I'm android beginner. I'm programming stock market application for android.I don't know any way to do that, what should I do to get data about stock market?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749

Comment: you have to know about the web-services..........

Answer (score 1):

First you should know what is API and Web-services meant; and how they are worked to-gather. E.g BSE API, Google Finance Api, Yahoo API.

After study them you can integrate them in android code; parse the data and result returned by web-services and then you can show them on android simulator.

This is how you should progress.

YOu can check this [library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) which helps you in integrating google finance api with your android code. Try searching for more sample code for such stuff and you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for lives in the java.net package. You'll want to create a URL that points to your webapp or the API for the stock market data, and then fetch it in an appropriate form. It should be something along the lines of:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/index.html");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
try {
  readStream(in);
 finally {
  in.close();
}
```

(Taken from http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html)

Make sure to request Network Access in your app permissions first.

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-dataAndroid/) stock market tutorial by IBM, showing how to retrieve the latest pricing information for the stocks using Internet data in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class in your activity class.
It extends `AsyncTask` which is a very good option for performing task in background as it'll improve the overall performance of application.

```
private class DownloadFromWeb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //Do whatever you want with result string...
    }
}
```

Now use this class as:

```
DownloadFromWeb task = new DownloadFromWeb ();
task.execute("http://www.google.com"); //replace the URL with your URL
```

Hope it helps !!!