# Get Html from web in android

Tags: android, html, url, android-webview

I want to get html from web but I can't. here is my code

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                URL url = null;
                url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    tv.append(line);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", "erorr connection "+ e.toString());
            }               
        }
    });
```

I also add permission from internet already. Target version 4.0.3

Comment: I want to get html from web to show in textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749

Comment: Solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327625/error-when-get-html-from-web-in-android/12328074#12328074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put network parts into background thread then update to foreground UI thread. You can use AsyncTask to do so.

Answer (score 3):

// Create HTTP Client

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http:// yoururl"); 
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
    InputStream is = entity.getContent(); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        sb.append(line + "\n");

    String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

    is.close(); // Close the stream
```